# How to scan input from a line in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have C/C++ background. I want to scan n integers given as input in a single line in python.
How can I make a list using this input?

Comment: *"Given as input"* how? Separated by spaces, tabs, commas, ...? Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), or tried anything?

Comment: As jonrsharpe said, we aren't here to write your code for you. **We are here to help you with problems that are occurring in your code.** Please show us what you've tried so far and someone will help you to solve it.